# Get only Visible TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

How can I check only that textboxes are that Visibility.Visible in the running program?

I have code for Winforms

```
foreach (var textbox in rootControl.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(t => t.IsVisible))
```

But I need that for WPF

I know, It should look smth like this

```
foreach (TextBox tb in this.FindName.OfType<TextBox>().Where(tb => tb.IsVisible))
```

Can you please help me this work well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate through your `Grid`, because all controls are children of the main Grid.

```
foreach (TextBox txt in grid1.Children.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x => x.IsVisible))
{

}
```

To use the Grid, you must name it first. Here it is `grid1`.

Comment: I'm really very happy : ) Thank You